# Find all class names in a WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection, class

In WPF, how do I use reflection to find all classes in a project? I'm interested in obtaining the ones whos names match a certain regular expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
 var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .Where(a => a.GetName().Name.StartsWith("MyCompany"));

var types =         from asm in assemblies
                    from type in asm.GetTypes()
            where Regex.IsMatch(type.FullName,"MyRegexp")
            select type.Name;
```

You can also load a specific assembly and filter the types you want.

Comment: My project uses more than one assembly, I'd like to know how to iterate through all of them. Anyway, thanks for the answer!

Comment: I edited the answer to look for all assemblies in the current AppDomain